# Recursively find all the nodes from an XML having a given argument with PHP / simpleXML

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

Like I said in the title, I was wondering whether it would be possible and how, to recursively parse an XML document and return all the nodes that have a given argument.

What I'm actually trying to do is to load and XHTML document and return all the nodes (P nodes, DIV nodes, etc.) that have a class equal to a previously defined value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use xpath to lookup the nodes, then just loop over:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($string);
$nodes = $xml->xpath("//*[@class='myclass']");

foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    // ...
}
```

(Not actually tested that, but it should be right.)

Comment: This XPath expression will match all nodes whose class attribute is exactly equal to "myclass". In other words, <div class="foo myclass"/> would _not_ match. The XPath would need to be modified with `contains()` plus spaces delimiters to avoid substring matches such as "myclass2"